# Converting list from string to int but there's a catch

Tags: python, list, class

I'll start off by saying that I don't know much about programming and I tried searching for answers but I didn't even know what to type in the search engine. So here goes.

```
class Point:
    def __init__ (self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __str__ (self):
        return "Members are: %s, %s" % (self.x, self.y)
```

I have this class which represents a point with its x and y coordinate.

I have a list `points = []` and if I manually append a point to that list e.g. `points.append(Point(-1.0, 3))` the output returns `(-1.0, 3)` I'm doing some calculations with these points but I don't think it matters if I put the code for that here.

Things get tricky because I have to input the numbers from a file. I already added them to another list and appended them using a loop. The problem is that the list is in **str** and if I convert it into **int** I get an error because of the decimal `.0` It says in my assignment that I have to keep the same format as the input.

The thing I don't understand is how does it keep the decimal `.0` when I input it like this `points.append(Point(-1.0, 3))` and is it possible to get the same output format with numbers from a file.

I tried converting it to float but then all the coordinates get decimal places.

Comment: Convert to `float` not `int`? I don't understand your problem here...

Comment: Yes, just use `float()` instead. You could either make all elements a float or only them with a `.0` or similar stuff.

Comment: @Julien Like I wrote at the end if I do that then all the coordinates get decimal places.

Comment: @bad_coder Yep, that's pretty much what the solution is to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to convert the inputs appropriately, with this try-catch mechanism, we first try `int`, then if we didn't successful, we continue with `float`.

```
def float_or_int(inp):
    try:
        n = int(inp)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            n = float(inp)
        except ValueError:
            print("it's not int or float")
    return n


input_1 = '10.3'
input_2 = '10.0'
input_3 = '10'

res1 = float_or_int(input_1)  
res2 = float_or_int(input_2)  
res3 = float_or_int(input_3)  

print(res1, type(res1))  # 10.3 <class 'float'>
print(res2, type(res2))  # 10.0 <class 'float'>
print(res3, type(res3))  # 10 <class 'int'>
```

I don't know how your inputs stored in the file/another list you are reading, but you get the idea how to parse a single input.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this:

```
proper_points = []
for x,y in points:
    float_x = float(x)
    int_y = int(y)
    coords = proper_points.append((x,y))
```

For your calculations, you could use the proper_points list instead of points

Comment: Good effort but yeah, the coordinates are going to be different.

Answer (score -5):

Man, do not reinvent the wheel. If you need to import data from file you can use `numpy` for example and the function `loadtxt`. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

I do not understand how your file is made and the format of the coordinate. In the bunch of code `points.append(Point(-1.0, 3))` the first number is a `float` the second one is an integer. Which format do you want?

For example in `file.dat` you have the `x,y` positions:

```
1 1
2 3
4 5
```

where the first column is the `x` position and the second one represents `y`. Then you can use this code

```
import numpy as np
points = np.loadtxt('file.dat', dtype = 'int')
```

in `points` you have all the positions inside the file and you can just use slicing to access them.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It answer the question because there is no necessity to create a class if you need to import from a file a series of xy points. You can just use a numpy array and the function that I have mentioned, for example. You do not have the problem of format and your code is cleaner. He says that he is quite new in programming, then I gave a useful tip.

Comment: First time using Python so I didn't know about that library. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @not_so_smart you can modify the `dtype` argument if you need float or integer. It has also other functionalities, but these are pertinent to your problem.